# MySQL failover & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database-replication

We run a fairly busy website, and currently it runs on a traditional one server LAMP stack.

The site has lots of legacy code, and the database is very big (approx 50GB when gzipped, so probably 4 or 5 times that..)

Unfortunately, the site is very fragile and although I'm quite confident load balancing servers with just one database backend I'm at a bit of a loss with replication and that sort of thing.

There's a lot of data written and read to the database at all times - I think we can probably failover to a slave MySQL database fairly easily, but I'm confused about what needs to happen when the master comes back online (if a master/slave setup is suitable...) does the master pick up any written rows when it comes back up from the slave or does something else have to happen?

Is there a standard way of making PHP decide whether to use a master or slave database?

Perhaps someone can point me in the way of a good blog post that can guide me?

Thanks,
John

Comment: So you're talking about a multi-master arrangement, or failing over to a read-only slave? Having automatic fail-over actually work is going to require significant work. Having a fail-over to read-only mode isn't as bad, but is still trouble.

Comment: master - master I suppose.. I did get the feeling that could be really hard to do..

Comment: It's not impossible, but it can take a lot of work to keep them on the same page. The paradox here is that sometimes adding resiliency degrades your availability because you've made a mistake. If this is a large-scale site with serious uptime concerns, you probably want to engage a replication consultant to get the right set-up out of the gate.

Comment: @tadman /second that. There are few tasks where I'm adamant about hiring expertise - and switching legacy code from 1 to n databases (in master mode) is one of them. If there's a budget, spent it. Spent it on a) getting trained to properly inspect your business logic and your code in order to make good decisions and b) to hire experts helping you to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a failover solution for your entire website, I found [this article](http://www.howto-expert.com/how-to-create-a-server-failover-solution/) interesting.  It talks about creating a clone of the mySql database and keeping them in sync with rsync.

A simpler solution would be to just backup your database periodically with a script that runs from a cron job.  Also set up a static web page failover solution.  [This website](http://helpfultips.website) has an article on setting that up.  That's the way we do it.  This way - if your database has issues, you can restore it using on of your backups, while you failover to your temporary static page.